# How to change background image of body element on click with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have implemented an background image in the body section via CSS file and it worked. However I needed this image to change depending on what tab the user clicks.

Now I thought this would be simple enough and after reading and trying the solutions in many posts here I can't figure out where I go wrong.

So basically my main setup was:

CSS:

```
body {
background-image: url(/bg04.png);
}
```

This works as it displays the background image.

Now I tried in to change the bg image in the part of the code that changes the whole scene when someone clicks on a tab:

```
var activate_doodle = function(e) {
     if (e) {
         e.preventDefault();
     }

     $("#text_input_container").css("display", "none");
     $("#doodle_input_container").css("display", "block");
     $("#change_keyboard").removeClass("active");
     $("#change_doodle").addClass("active");
     document.getElementById("colorPicker").click();

     $('body').css('background-imgage','url(http://example.com/bg04-2.png');

};
```

But it does not change the image. I tried copying and pasting the absolute URL into my browser and the path to the pic is correct.

I also tried taking it away from my CSS putting the whole thing in my initializing JS sequence and then the same lines in the click events.

I really appreciate your help guys.

Thanks.

Comment: `background-image` is the correct attribute used instead of `background-imgage` note the im **g** age. If that is a typo let us know

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`'background-im`***`g`***`age'`
Remove `g` from the attribute — it should be [`background-image`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image):

`$('body').css('background-image','url(http://example.com/bg04-2.png');`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you type error

```
$('body').css('background-image','url(http://example.com/bg04-2.png)');
```

Answer (score -1):

```
document.getElementById("colorPicker").click( function(e) {
if (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}

$("#text_input_container").css("display", "none");
$("#doodle_input_container").css("display", "block");
$("#change_keyboard").removeClass("active");
$("#change_doodle").addClass("active");
$('body').css('background-image','url(http://example.com/bg04-2.png');
```

};)

may be try to add an event listener.

Comment: Why are you using vanilla JavaScript to grab an element by `id` in one spot and jQuery to do the same in all other spots?

Comment: i was using snippets of your code you had this " document.getElementById("colorPicker").click();
" in you function so i just tailored it a bit.